# Extracting year from two different date format

Tags: r, date

I have column say `x` which has two different date formats `12/31/1998` and `12/--/98`. As you can see, in the second format `date` is missing and `year` is in 2 digits.

I need to extract `year` from all the dates in my column. So, when I am using `Year<- data.frame(format(df$x, "%Y"))` it returning `year` for first format. For second format, it is returning `NA`.

I would appreciate all the help. Thanks.

Comment: Do you need a four digit number for the year, or can you live with two digits?

Comment: My `class` is` factor` in the `data frame`. But, later I am converting them to `date` format using `"%m/%d/%Y"`. Using `basename` as suggested in the following answer would solve my problem.

Comment: Does the data always have `--` for the day when the year is in the 2 digit format?

Comment: Data always have `--` for the day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get a bit creative and specify an ugly format for the missing data, and then just keep one of the valid responses:

```
vals <- c("12/31/1998", "12/--/98")
out <- pmax(
         as.Date(vals, "%m/%d/%Y"),
         as.Date(paste0("01",vals), "%d%m/--/%y"),
         na.rm=TRUE
       )
format(out, "%Y")
#[1] "1998" "1998"
```

Comment: Actually, I was thinking like this. I was about to put some date in missing data. This is great answer which was I exactly looking for. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: What about a date that is `12/01/98`? I am not clear on whether the string always has `--` when the year is in the 2 digit format.

Comment: @dayne - OP specified they have two formats - this covers both of them as far as I can tell.

Comment: Right, but this returns `0098` for `12/01/98`

Comment: @dayne your solution works perfectly when dates have multiple formats. Hence, I am using your solution which is elegant.

Comment: Both solutions are great. I just want to thank you everyone for your help.

Comment: @user3669801 Be aware that neither of these solutions work for 2 digit years before 1969. I just asked a [follow-up](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38580070/1623354) in case you're curious.

Comment: @dayne Thanks. My dates are not before 1969.  So, everything is good. Thanks again for following up.

Answer (score 2):

If they are all in the format where the year is the last number after "/" you can use `basename`. Then you just need to covert the 2 character years to a four year format:

```
vals <- c("12/31/1998", "12/--/98", "68", "69")
yrs <- basename(vals)
yrs <- ifelse(nchar(yrs) == 2, format(as.Date(yrs, format = "%y"), "%Y"), yrs)
yrs
# [1] "1998" "1998" "2068" "1969"
```

The issue is it does not work with dates older than 1969.