# How to handle an ambiguous century in datetime objects?

Tags: r, datetime

I am playing around with datetime stuff in R and cannot figure out how to alter the time origin to accept older dates. For example:

```
vals <- as.character(60:70)
as.POSIXct(vals, origin="1900-01-01", format = "%y")
# [1] "2060-07-25 EDT" "2061-07-25 EDT" "2062-07-25 EDT" "2063-07-25 EDT"
# [5] "2064-07-25 EDT" "2065-07-25 EDT" "2066-07-25 EDT" "2067-07-25 EDT"
# [9] "2068-07-25 EDT" "1969-07-25 EDT" "1970-07-25 EDT"
```

Is it possible to adjust the origin such that `as.POSIXct` will return 1960 for an input of "60"? What is the best way to handle an ambiguous century?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make `as.POSIXct` return 1960 for an input of `"60"`.  See `?strptime`:

```
 ‘%y’ Year without century (00-99).  On input, values 00 to 68 are
      prefixed by 20 and 69 to 99 by 19 - that is the behaviour
      specified by the 2004 and 2008 POSIX standards, but they do
      also say ‘it is expected that in a future version the default
      century inferred from a 2-digit year will change’.
```

You need to prepend the century to the string and use the `"%Y"` format if you want different behavior with `as.POSIXct`.

```
vals <- as.character(60:70)
as.POSIXct(paste0("19",vals), format = "%Y")
```

---

If some of the two-digit dates are after 2000, you can use `ifelse` or something similar to prepend a different century.

```
newvals <- paste0(ifelse(vals < "20", "20", "19"), vals)
```

Comment: I did read that -- I just assumed there would be a way to change the default behavior.

Comment: @dayne: There are not usually ways to subvert behavior that adheres to international standards.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you might want some years greater than 2000, prepending 19 to the vector might not be desirable.

In this case subtracting 100 years might be better.

```
library(lubridate)
vals <- as.character(60:70)
vals <- as.POSIXct(vals, origin="1900-01-01", format = "%y")
vals[year(vals)>2059] <- vals[year(vals)>2059] - years(100)
vals

 [1] "1960-07-25 CDT" "1961-07-25 CDT" "1962-07-25 CDT"
 [4] "1963-07-25 CDT" "1964-07-25 CDT" "1965-07-25 CDT"
 [7] "1966-07-25 CDT" "1967-07-25 CDT" "1968-07-25 CDT"
[10] "1969-07-25 CDT" "1970-07-25 CDT"
```

Comment: Clever hack. I have not looked at the `lubridate` package at all, yet.

Comment: Many of us who studied with Hadley know the hadleyverse better than base R. `lubridate` is a good one.

Comment: This only works if the POSIX standard remains unchanged, but `?strptime` says is expected to change at some point in the future.